# Sending .Wav file over the network using NAudio

Tags: c#, .net, audio, naudio

I am working with NAudio to send audio files .wav to be exact from one pc to another.

I have tried sending the message over the network stream but i have no way of checking whether the message had been sent correctly or not because so far i am having problems with receiving the code.

Here's the sending code.

```
public void StartConnection()
    {
        _connection = new TcpClient("localhost",1111);
        _stream = _connection.GetStream();
        SendFile(_stream,_waveStream);
    }

public void SendFile(NetworkStream StreamToWrite,WaveStream StreamToSend)
    {
        WaveFileWriter write = new WaveFileWriter(StreamToWrite,StreamToSend.WaveFormat);
        byte[] decoded = FromStreamToByte(StreamToSend);
        write.Write(decoded,0,decoded.Length);
        write.Flush();
    }
```

and here is the receiving code

```
public void ListenConnection()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,1111);
        _listener.Start();
        TcpClient receiver = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        _stream = receiver.GetStream();
    }

public void ReadFile(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        WaveFileReader read = new WaveFileReader(stream);
    }
```

Now i am having trouble on where to continue with receiving code because if i call `read` method of `read` then it asks for a byte array, offset and length. But why it asks for an array is beyond me after all its just receiving data.

Any advice on how should i proceed further with the `ReadFile` method.

UPDATE---

During Debugging i found out that NetworkStream that was being passed to SendFile for use in WaveFileWriter has not determined length and so it gives the `Stream Does not Support Seek Operations`. However i don't understand why it gives this error because its prototype says it can accept any Stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use WaveFileWriter with a NetworkStream, because the WAV file header contains length information that is not known until the whole file has been written. So the header is written last, requiring a seekable stream.

Instead of streaming a WAV file, just send the PCM audio (and format information first if you need) and put it into a WAV file at the other end.

Comment: Now that i notice my question title is a bit misleading because i am not exactly sending a .wav file over networkstream. Instead the `StreamToSend` in SendFile is just yet another stream that i obtained following [this](http://opensebj.blogspot.com/2009/02/introduction-to-using-naudio.html) tutorial.

Comment: If you've already got a WAV fike, just send it over a NetworkStream. No need to involve WaveFileWriter at all.

Comment: Hi @MarkHeath Could you give us an example of how to send data over the network captured by WasapiLoopbackCapture?
How can I send the PCM audio? Thanks!